# How to show error message when user does not exist using Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm new to Spring Security. I tried to search with criteria `is:question [spring-security] error message when user does not exist` but no post helps.

Currently I use `Spring Security 3.1` to authenticate user in my web application. My implementation as below:

1. use `DaoAuthenticationProvider` as `AuthenticationProvider`
2. write an implementation for `UserDetailsService` which is used by `DaoAuthenticationProvider`

Here is `userDetailsServiceImpl` bean:

```
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User existingUser = this.userDao.getUserByUsername(username);
        // TODO create a schema for storing ROLEs in database
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        roles.add(Role.USER);

        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                existingUser.getUsername(), existingUser.getPassword(), existingUser.getEnable(), true, true, true, roles);
        return user;
    }

}
```

I show error message in `login.ftl`(I'm using freemarker) as below:

```
<#if Session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION?? 
    && Session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message?has_content>
    <br />Message: ${Session.SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message} 
</#if>
```

Everything worked fine, except no message is shown up on login page when non existing username is entered. I checked `console` but didn't see anything out of the ordinary.

```
2013-06-09 02:25:38.082 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [net.dntuan.training.mvc.security.authentication.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; '' (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:366)
2013-06-09 02:25:38.162 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction (HibernateTransactionManager.java:416)
2013-06-09 02:25:38.167 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:426)
2013-06-09 02:25:38.234 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection@2b9fd66a] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:487)
Hibernate: select this_.id as id1_1_0_, this_.enable as enable2_1_0_, this_.fullname as fullname3_1_0_, this_.password as password4_1_0_, this_.username as username5_1_0_ from public.user this_ where this_.username=?
2013-06-09 02:25:38.367 [TRACE] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:936)
2013-06-09 02:25:38.367 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction rollback (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:844)
2013-06-09 02:25:38.367 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] (HibernateTransactionManager.java:570)
2013-06-09 02:25:38.371 [TRACE] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization (AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:965)
2013-06-09 02:25:38.372 [DEBUG] [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction (HibernateTransactionManager.java:632)
```

Is it possible to show an error message in this case?

Comment: Is userDao.getUserByUsername throwing UsernameNotFoundException somewhere?  Looks to me like the user will always be authenticated unless your DAO throws UsernameNotFoundException somewhere, since you are creating a new Spring Security User enabled, regardless of the existingUser returned by your DAO

Comment: `UsernameNotFoundException` is not thrown, and no another `exception` is thrown neither(I did watch console carefully). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are implementing UserDetailsService, you will need to throw UsernameNotFoundException manually, in order to tell Spring Security the user trying to login was not found. It would be something like this:

```
User existingUser = this.userDao.getUserByUsername(username);
if (existingUser != null) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
    roles.add(Role.USER);

    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            existingUser.getUsername(), existingUser.getPassword(), existingUser.getEnable(), true, true, true, roles);
    return user;
} else {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It has worked but I don't understand **why `NullPointerException` is not thrown** at `existingUser.getUsername()` in my code although `existingUser` is `null`??

Comment: Good question. Depends on whatever your DAO is returning when getUserByUsername is invoked. Isn't it returning an empty object?

Comment: I debug and see that `existingUser` is `null` now. If it was not `null`, your code would be similar to my code :D

Comment: @ControllerAdvice
ExceptionController is not able to listen UsernameNotFoundException